# Website from JPG templates from OCR of the images

Tags: template

Somebody has given me some jpg's, and expect me to create a website from them.
With an online tool, I am able to OCR them.

Is it some tool that will let me create a proper site from the jpg's?

Would it be OK to put the jpg's and the OCRed text in tags?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creation of websites from JPEGs is an ancient idea. Do not do it. Build HTML that looks like the JPEGs or Refuse the job - it drops your standards and more importantly the standard of the internet.

But, if you must do it, You may use [Adobe Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks.html). It can slice images into multiple small images and generates the required HTML ([see Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d35d-7fff.html#WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d35d-7ffb)) that can be linked to other pages.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a website from the JPG but it is not advisable. There are a couple of good reasons for this. Two important ones are to do with Text and Design.

- If it is simply and image then there will be no text which means it will be very difficult to be found by any search engine. This is the case whether you put it up as one large JPG or multiple smaller ones.
- I suspect the JPGs are from a printed brochure. Not unreasonably people might think that this translates pretty simply to online. It doesn't. The layout for online and the motivation in design for online is very different to print. In online you are often looking to provide the next action from the homepage. In print it is static.

All that said to answer your actual question. Yes you would need to put the JPG and the text in tags.

At its simplest you could just have:

```
<html>
<head><title>Title of your page</title></head>
<body>
<img src="path/to/your.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```